# how to create and extrude a bmesh face

Tags: python, bmesh, extrude

I would like to programmatically create and extrude polygons. I've found several examples of code (e.g. [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49857/bmesh-extrude-face-and-end-up-with-closed-mesh)), but none of them are currently working for me. As a simple example, I am trying to get things working first with a defined circular face and then extrude that face. Here is the code defining the circular bmesh:

```
import bpy, bmesh
from math import *

NUMVERTS = 1000
Dphi = 2*pi/NUMVERTS
# calculate x,y coordinate pairs
coords = [(cos(i*Dphi),sin(i*Dphi),0) for i in range(NUMVERTS)]

bm = bmesh.new()
for v in coords:
    bm.verts.new(v)
bm.faces.new(bm.verts)

bm.normal_update()

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("circle")
bm.to_mesh(me)
# add bmesh to scene
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("circle",me)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
bpy.context.scene.update()
```

Which results in a 2D circle

[image: 2D circle]

I then want to extrude that face in z by some amount resulting in something like:

[image: Extrusion]

I would like to do everything in a python script without having to select anything in the GUI. Also, I'm using a circle as a placeholder example here -- I ultimately want to import much more complicated 2D (XY) polygons and extrude them in Z by some amount. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Here is the extrusion part filled in:

```
import bpy, bmesh
from math import *
from mathutils import Vector

NUMVERTS = 1000
Dphi = 2*pi/NUMVERTS
# calculate x,y coordinate pairs
coords = [(cos(i*Dphi),sin(i*Dphi),0) for i in range(NUMVERTS)]

bm = bmesh.new()
for v in coords:
    bm.verts.new(v)

# think of this new vertices as bottom of the extruded shape
bottom = bm.faces.new(bm.verts)

# next we create top via extrude operator, note it doesn't move the new face
# we make our 1 face into a list so it can be accepted to geom
top = bmesh.ops.extrude_face_region(bm, geom=[bottom])

# here we move all vertices returned by the previous extrusion
# filter the "geom" list for vertices using list constructor
bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=Vector((0,0,1)), verts=[v for v in top["geom"] if isinstance(v,bmesh.types.BMVert)])

bm.normal_update()

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("circle")
bm.to_mesh(me)
# add bmesh to scene
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("circle",me)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
bpy.context.scene.update()
```

The hard part is grasping the habit of having this dictionary return type from the operations. It's a dictionary containing definition for "geom" that contains a single list where all the verts, edges and faces are listed one after another. You are then supposed to make a list of the verts, edges or faces with python list construction where you check for the element type using isinstance(), depending on what you need for each operation.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Similarly to the link in your q, can use bmesh operators, in this case I've used [solidify](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.solidify), Note you must set the normal before calling the operator to get the desired result.  Also note that `face.normal = (0, 0, -1)` (commented out) could (preferably?) be used in place of `bm.normal_update()`.

```
import bpy, bmesh
from math import radians, sin, cos

NUMVERTS = 100
Dphi = radians(360) / NUMVERTS
# calculate x,y coordinate pairs
coords = [(cos(i * Dphi), sin(i * Dphi), 0) for i in range(NUMVERTS)]

bm = bmesh.new()
verts = [bm.verts.new(v) for v in coords]

face = bm.faces.new(verts)
bm.normal_update()
# or face.normal = (0, 0, -1)
bmesh.ops.solidify(bm, geom=[face], thickness=1.0)

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("circle")
bm.to_mesh(me)
# add bmesh to scene
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("circle",me)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
```

However I've found if you are going to do for multiple faces then making the "wall" faces is significantly faster.  (that's my experience using similar to create 1000's of [OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_buildings#Roof) buildings that are basically an extrusion of an ngon.)

```
import bpy, bmesh
from math import radians, cos, sin

from mathutils import Vector

NUMVERTS = 100
Dphi = radians(360) / NUMVERTS
height = 1.0
# calculate x,y coordinate pairs
coords = [(cos(i * Dphi), sin(i * Dphi), 0) for i in range(NUMVERTS)]

bm = bmesh.new()
verts = [bm.verts.new(v) for v in coords]
roofverts = [bm.verts.new(v.co + Vector((0, 0, height))) for v in verts]
# pop one on the end to make ring
roofverts.append(roofverts[0])  
verts.append(verts[0]) 
for i in range(len(roofverts) - 1):
    wall = bm.faces.new([verts[i], roofverts[i], roofverts[i+1], verts[i+1]])
    #wall.material_index = matidx 
# pop off to remove.
verts.pop()
roofverts.pop()
floor = bm.faces.new(verts)
top = bm.faces.new(roofverts)

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("circle")
bm.to_mesh(me)
# add bmesh to scene
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("circle",me)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)
```